# Access django by WAN IP instead of domain

Tags: django, traefik, cookiecutter-django

I'm using the pydanny-cookiecutter, and during the initial prompts, I gave a domain that I no longer wish to use.

How can I update to just be able to access the service by the WAN IP of the digital ocean droplet I am running in?

So far I've opened ports 5000 and 5555 in the droplet and manually (ssh into postgres container) inserted a new record into django_sites with ID 2 and the domain and name both as the WAN IP. I've also updated the SITE_ID=2 in the settings base.py.

I've uploaded the traefik.yml to the following, but still unable to reach the pages when I go to WANIP:5000 or WANIP:5555

```
log:
  level: INFO

entryPoints:
  web:
    # http
    address: ":80"
    http:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/routing/entrypoints/#entrypoint
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: web-secure

  web-secure:
    # https
    address: ":443"

  flower:
    address: ":5555"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#lets-encrypt
    acme:
      email: "<REDACTED>@gmail.com"
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/https/acme/#httpchallenge
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

http:
  routers:
    web-secure-router:
      rule: "HostRegexp(`<REDACTED WAN IP>`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      middlewares:
        - csrf
      service: django
      tls:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
        certResolver: letsencrypt

    flower-secure-router:
      rule: "HostRegexp(`<REDACTED WAN IP>`)"
      entryPoints:
        - flower
      service: flower
      tls:
        # https://docs.traefik.io/master/routing/routers/#certresolver
        certResolver: letsencrypt

  middlewares:
    csrf:
      # https://docs.traefik.io/master/middlewares/headers/#hostsproxyheaders
      # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax
      headers:
        hostsProxyHeaders: ["X-CSRFToken"]

  services:
    django:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://django:5000

    flower:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://flower:5555

providers:
  # https://docs.traefik.io/master/providers/file/
  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    watch: true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you use an **IP**, the **SSL certificate** generation will not work, and so that'll throw a warning in browser saying :

> it's a dangerous site.

What you want to do is open up ports **80** and **443** in the **droplet**, and access the application through `http://[IP]`.

No ports in the links because you are configuring Traefik to route http (port 80) and https (port 443) requests to **Django**.

This is not a solution for flower, but I don't have much experience with flower to say.